# Как исключит папку но за пушить ее содержимое?

Tags: git, gitignore

есть така cтруктура

---

- dist

  - component

    - file1
    - file2
- .gitignore

---

как настроить  *gitignore* таким образом что бы получилаcь такая структупа
при **git push**

---

- file1
- file2
- .gitignore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В `.gitignore`:

```
!component/file1
!component/file2

component
```